# Parse a string to an Enum value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, enums

How can I parse a string in VB.NET to enum value?

Example I have this enum:

```
Public Enum Gender
    NotDefined
    Male
    Female
End Enum
```

how can I convert a string "Male" to the `Gender` enum's `Male` value?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
Dim val = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(Gender), "Male"), Gender)
```

Comment: what if i don't know the type and wanted to convert generally. in this example you specified `Male`. i saved the enum value in database and am trying to get it back. in this case i might not know thw actual value that i saved since am converting toString

Comment: You should save the related Enum type with the value, say "Namespaces.EnumName". After you can use reflection to get the Type object by name: Dim t = Type.GetType("Namespaces.EnumName") and pass the 't' instead of 'GetType(Gender)'. Also you will have to cast the result value. To do this you must know the specific enum type while writing code.

Comment: In .NET 4.0 the syntax is simply: `Parse(enumType As System.Type, value As String) As Object`

Comment: He's asking for the value of the enum, but this snippet just returns an Enum object based from the string. Should be: `DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(Gender), "Male"), Integer)`

Answer (score 20):

See [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx).

Comment: There is only Parse() method. Not sure where is the Enum.TryParse() method?

Comment: @David: Enum.TryParse() is available in .NET 4

Comment: correct link, can't edit the answer as it is less then 30 characters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx

Answer (score 5):

> how can I convert a string "Male" to the Gender enum's Male value?

The accepted solution returns an Enum object. To return the value you want this solution:

```
dim MyGender as string = "Male"
dim Value as integer
Value = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(Gender), MyGender), Integer)
```

Can also do it this way:

```
value = cInt([enum].Parse(GetType(Gender), MyGender))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parse to be case insensitive, you can use the following:

```
[Enum].Parse(Gender, DirectCast(MyGender, String), True)
```

This will handle `dim MyGender as string = "Male"` or `dim MyGender as string = "male"`