# How to retrieve an Enum member given its name

Tags: .net, vb.net

It's very easy I have the following Enum

```
Public Enum TCheckStatus
        Checked
        NotChecked
        Indeterminate 
    End Enum
```

I want to get the Index of the given name found in the enum, what's the best way?!!

**For Example:**

Suppose I have "NotChecked" string , I want the output to be 1

Comment: What is a given name found in the enum?

Comment: Suppose I have "NotChecked" string , I want the output to be 1

Comment: Do you want the index or the value? (They might not be the same if the enum has been declared with explicit values, and I can't think of any good reason why you would need the index rather than the value. Relying on the index rather than the value would be very brittle.)

Comment: @LukeH Yes you are right, it's better to use the value but I miss the right words to explain my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx). It retrieves an array of the names of the constants in a specified enumeration.

```
Dim notCheckedStatus  = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(TCheckStatus), "NotChecked"), TCheckStatus)
Dim allStatusNames    = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(TCheckStatus))
Dim indexOfNotChecked = Array.IndexOf(AllStatusNames, "NotChecked") '=1'
```

1. line: parses a `string` variable to an enum-value
2. line: returns all enum-values of a given enum-type as `Array`
3. line: returns the index of a given enum-value in that `Array`

Of course to solve your question you only need this:

```
Array.IndexOf([Enum].GetNames(GetType(TCheckStatus)), "NotChecked")
```

Comment: This answer returns the Index, in some scenarios it can differ from the Value. For example an Enum that start at value 1 or when something got deleted or rearranged. The Value can be retrieved by following vb.net code: `CInt(System.Enum.Parse(GetType(TCheckStatus), "NotChecked"))`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give precise vb syntax, but I'll write it in C# so see if you can use it:

```
int index = (int)Enum.Parse( typeof(TCheckStatus), "NotChecked");
```

`index` is 1 in this case. If you give an invalid string (not a member of the enum), it will throw an exception. If this is not what you want, you can use `Enum.TryParse` instead.

If you already have the enum, you can just cast it to a int to get the index:

```
var myEnum = TCheckStatus.NotChecked;
int index = (int)myEnum;
```

Comment: Note that if the enum has been declared with explicit values then `(int)myEnum` will give you the *value*, not necessarily the index. Using the index is very brittle and not a good idea, since a dev might legitimately assume that the members can safely be re-ordered as long as they keep their values.

Comment: When I said index I really meant value, but good that you made it clear for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

To get arrays of the names and their integer equivalents with the Enum methods in VB.net, please use GetNames() and GetValues() method. Use Parse() to get the index. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
int Output = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TCheckStatus), "NotChecked");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Dim val as integer = cint(DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(TCheckStatus), _
                          "NotChecked"), TCheckStatus)
```

[StackOverflow - Parse a string to an Enum value in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852141/parse-a-string-to-an-enum-value-in-vb-net)