# Passing a variable to an Enum

Tags: vb.net, enums

I'm looping through a collection of rows ordered by a field called "rIndex". I've created an Enum and assigned the name of the item to the number I want the index to be. For example

Public Enum RowOrder

RowA = 1 
RowB = 3 
RowC = 2

I'm using a select case to properly identify the rows I want out of the collection.

```
for each row in collection

Select Case row

Case rowA, rowB, rowC
row.rIndex = RowOrder.( 'I want to put the variable row name here, something like row.tostring ) 

Case Else 
'Do nothing  

next row
```

Does anyone know how to pass a variable to the field of an Enum so it will return its number?

Comment: I would think an Enum being just an array would have some kind of method to search through it, or at least an exposed function to harvest this information from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to cast your `enum` variable to `int`

```
Dim value As Integer = CInt([Enum].Parse(GetType(RowOrder), [Enum].GetName(GetType(RowOrder), myRowOrder)))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852141/parse-a-string-to-an-enum-value-in-vb-net

Comment: Found the above just as you were answering. Thanks for the assistance.