# VB.net Express 2010 eval?

Tags: vb.net

The scenario is this:
I want to set the formborderstyle using a combobox.

I can set the borderstyle to "None" successfully with these methods:

```
Form1.FormBorderStyle = 0
```

Or

```
Form1.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
```

---

How could I do this with a string?

```
Dim formstyle As String
formstyle = "Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle." & ComboBox1.Text
Form1.FormBorderStyle = formstyle
```

I get this error: *Conversion from string "Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.No" to type 'Integer' is not valid.*

---

It seems like Form1.formborderstyle only takes integers. Without actually using the integers, is there a way i can convert the string to the integer counterpart...sort of like an eval?

Ultimately I was hoping it looked something like:

```
Dim formstyle As String
formstyle = "Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle." & ComboBox1.Text
Form1.FormBorderStyle = eval(formstyle)
```

Comment: What does your question title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enum.(Try)Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx):

> ## `Enum.Parse`
>
> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.

The documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/852156/242520) has an example of the syntax. You're probably after something like:

```
Form1.FormBorderStyle = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(FormBorderStyle), ComboBox1.Text), FormBorderStyle)
```

Comment: For some reason im getting: Requested value 'Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None' was not found.

Comment: Try using just `None`. enum's don't know their namespace. They just know their values.

Comment: @user1950278 Look at the example I wrote and compare it to yours. I don't concatenate `Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.` to the start of the enum name.