# How to get the integer value of an enum

Tags: vb.net, enums

I have an enum that goes like this:

```
Enum Cards
   club = 1
   spade = 2
   hearts = 3
   diamond = 4
End Enum
```

Now, what I want to do is whenever I enter the string "club" or whatever from enum, I can get its integer value.

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse a string to an Enum value in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852141/parse-a-string-to-an-enum-value-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code.

```
 Foo = CType(System.Enum.Parse(GetType(Cards), "club"), Cards)
```

Comment: it has an error saying this "Type provided must be of Enum"

Comment: ok, the error's my fault. I fixed it and the code works like charm. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd use TryParse as shown below.  The value returned is enum type, but the type is an integer and can be used as such.

```
Enum Cards
    club = 1
    spade = 2
    hearts = 3
    diamond = 4
End Enum

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim enumVlaue As Cards
    If Not [Enum].TryParse("spade", enumVlaue) Then
        'did not convert
        Stop
    End If

    Dim foo As Integer = enumVlaue + 42
End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

If it's an integer value, try:

```
enumVariable * 1
```