# How to set messagebox icon using a string variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been trying to make a program open a messagebox with the icon identified by a string variable, but I can't figure out how! I've tried using something like this

```
MessageBox.Show("Message here", _
    "Message", _
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, _
    MessageBoxIcon. + IconVariable)
```

But it gives me the error:
*'MessageBoxIcon' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.*

Comment: [Why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) do you want `IconVariable` to be a string specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a string to an Enum value in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852141/parse-a-string-to-an-enum-value-in-vb-net)

Comment: You're trying to do something that, on the face of it, makes no sense. If you have a legitimate reason, it's up to you to explain that. You ALWAYS need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Function from the link suggested by @GSerg in comments.

```
Private Function GetIconEnum(s As String) As MessageBoxIcon
    Dim icon As MessageBoxIcon
    Try
        icon = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(MessageBoxIcon), s), MessageBoxIcon)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return MessageBoxIcon.None
    End Try
    Return Icon
End Function

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim IconVariable As String = "Question"
    MessageBox.Show("Message here", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, GetIconEnum(IconVariable))
End Sub
```